# Why are Google API queries through simplejson returning "responseData": null?

Tags: python, ajax, simplejson, google-search-api

I'm trying to screenscrape the first result of a Google search using Python and simplejson, but I can't access the search results the way that many examples online demonstrate. Here's a snippet:

```
url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % (query)
search_results = urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.load(search_results)
try:
    results = json['responseData']['results'] # always fails at this line
    first_result = results[0]
except:
    print "attempt to set results failed"
```

When I go to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&stackoverflow (or anything else substituted for the %s) in a browser, it displays the line "{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "clip sweeping", "responseStatus": 204}." Is there some other way to access the results of a Google search in Python besides trying to use the apparently empty responseData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the &q=. You also should consider using an api-key. http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/. Besides that plain string contaction wont work, you need to escape the parameter.

```
 url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q= ' + urllib.quote_plus(query)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, evilpie! But, after I added the &q=, I still get a null value for responseData. Would using an API key change this? If not, do you know what would?

I should have clarified that I had set query equal to urllib.urlencode({'q' : 'site:linkedin.com %s' % (company)}), but did not include it in the snippet.